# How to shift a PDF content up down left or right using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am wanting to find a way that I can use iText sharp to move or "shift" the content of a PDF in any direction. I am currently adding overlay art to PDF's using the Stamper and such, and have noticed there is a positional coordiate system in the method "AddTemplate() like so:

```
AddTemplate(pageNumber, x, y)
```

The problem is that I need to use measurements of inches. Like a 10TH OF A INCH, ect. How can I do this and how much is the x/y corrdinate move n it's position at the current moment if I do :

```
AddTemplate(i, 15, 23)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just found out that 20 pix with my dimensions is exactly 1/4 of an inch. So I think I can work this out now. I guess i can give the user a key in the console application of how the dem work, and then use the PDF copy to create a newly shifted document. At that point, now I can run it through the next process. Please let me know if there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Unless someone has changed the defaults there should be 72 units per inch which means that a quarter of an inch should actually be 18 units.

Comment: Cool. I am still learning technologies about PDF's. Thanks.  I also came across some Java code I can interpret into C#, and so am checking that out. If I find a answer, I will post it.  Thanks again.