# Shifting the entire document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am needing to be able to shift a document in iTextSharp while using PDFStamper to stamp overlays on the document. It is being used for statement files. We want to be able to shift the margins while doing a page iteration loop using the PDFReader. How could I go about this? Do I have to go through the full process of stamping the file, then create yet another file that does the shifting. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this related to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23790532/231316 Can you explain "shift" some more? "Margins" are a convenience that iText provides during creation but they don't actually exist within a PDF. If you can provide a sample image of what you're trying to do, before and after, we might be able to help more.

Comment: I need to move all content up say .25 inches, or maybe even on x coordinate .75 inches, while going through the process of doing the PDF stamping. I cannot show example as I work with banking statements.

Comment: See, what I am trying to do is acomplish thi sis one run. I do not want to ad even more processes to my code. For example, a run to insert backers and overlays onto a dicument. Then, create yet another run, to change the margins of each page. I was trying to find away to do it all at the same time. I am not using the Document methods or the PDFCopy methods, but the readers and PDFStamper to add the overlays. So I wanted to know if I could say, stamp the overlay, and then take the imported page, and shift it down by one inch. Something like that.

Comment: Is there no way to nip this in the bud early and just fix the source documents?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798583/itext-how-to-move-down-the-current-contents-in-a-pdf/12813721#12813721) what you want?

Comment: Yes, and thank you. Sorry, for the late reply. I am in the process of moving and have a 6 ear old boy and 3 year old girl, so got my hands full over the holiday weekend.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Did you got any solution ? I am too stuck with the same requirement. Please help